# python elasticsearch-dsl parent child relationship

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I started using the python library [elasticsearch-dsl](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

I am trying to implement a parent-child relationship but it is not working:

```
    class Location(DocType):
        name = String(analyzer='snowball', fields={'raw': String(index='not_analyzed')})
        latitude = String(analyzer='snowball')
        longitude = String(analyzer='snowball')
        created_at = Date()

   class Building(DocType):
       parent = Location()
```

Comment: Code example? Actual problem?

Comment: @ScottM updated the code sample

Comment: There are a lot of different options to implementing object relations in the relational database sense. You could decide to embed documents-within-documents (basically, a sub-table within a table, if you will.) Or reimplement a relational database "join" primitive. Would help if you explained the approach(es) you're considering, technical challenges encountered, etc. Your quesiton is too broad for anyone to give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 11):

elasticsearch-dsl has parent-child relationship built in using [MetaField](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/persistence.html#class-meta-options):

```
class Location(DocType):
    name = String(analyzer='snowball', fields={'raw': String(index='not_analyzed')})
    latitude = String(analyzer='snowball')
    longitude = String(analyzer='snowball')
    created = Date()

    class Meta:
        doc_type = 'location' 

class Building(DocType):

    class Meta:
        doc_type = 'building'
        parent = MetaField(type='location')
```

How to insert and query (HT to @Maresh):
  - DSL get: `ChildDoc.get(id=child_id, routing=parent_id)`
  - DSL insert: I believe it's `child.save(id=child_id, routing=parent_id)`
  - Dictionary insert: specify `'_parent': parent_id` in dictionary

Comment: Do you happen to know how to test the parent_id when saving the child, I'm struggling with this.

Comment: @Maresh to insert you specify a `_parent` key in the dictionary. For search you do `MyDoc.get(id=doc_id, routing=parent_id)`.

Comment: So when I save the child is do: child.save(parent=parent.meta.id) ? Thanks man. Edit your answer with that, it's quite useful and the doc does not say anything about that.

Comment: @Maresh I believe it's `child.save(id=child_id, routing=parent_id)`. Can you check?

Comment: Confirmed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Maresh How does one get the parent from getting the child? What does the search query look like?

Comment: Hmm I'm not totalky sure, I use ES as document store for this one. But you'll have a _parent with the Metadata I believe, there are some example in the ES doc.

Comment: When you say document store... you mean you treating the document store as if a relational database with a foreign key which is basically `routing`?

Comment: How can we form the has child query with  Elasticsearch DSL  in python

Comment: UPDATE: No longer works in ElasticSearch 6. Must use `Join` field instead.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks all.
The simple and messy solution that worked for me was to use:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Mapping

mcc = Mapping(typeChild)
mcc.meta('_parent', type=typeParent)
mcc.field(fieldName, 'string', fielddata=True, store=True)
mcc.save(index)
```

BEFORE creating the parent doc-type